# python (optimizing) bubble sort

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, array, sorting

I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (the first under Optimizing bubble sort) a pseudo-code to bubble sort and I implemented it in Python.

I am posting my implementation here because I'm new to Python, and I'm looking mostly for programming in a more pythonic way.

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    n = len(array)
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(n - 1):
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
                swapped = True
        n -= 1
    return array


def main():
    array = [1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 6]
    array = bubbleSort(array)
    print(array)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd love to know if there are any stuff that I can optimize (syntactic-wise), like the fact that I'm writing `swapped = True`, and afterward changing it again, and again ... which thing annoys me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bubbleSort` function both mutate the array in-place **and** `return` it. This is unnecessary at best, error-prone at worse since a user could think that it return a *new* list.

So I would remove the `return` statement and have the `main` look like:

```
def main():
    array = [1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 6]
    bubbleSort(array)
    print(array)
```

---

Even better, as your `main` is mostly a test of `bubbleSort`, you could rename it as such and accept the array as parameter:

```
def test_bubble_sort(array):
    print(array, end=' => ')
    bubbleSort(array)
    print(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_bubble_sort([1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 6])
    test_bubble_sort([9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Also a beginner but one thing I would like to point out is naming function, [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) states:

> Function Names
>   Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

So, in your case write `bubble_sort` instead of `bubbleSort`.

Answer (score 4):

> like the fact that I'm writing swapped = True, and afterward changing
>   it again, and again annoys me.

The truth is that you do not even need that `swapped` variable as you can simplify your function and get rid of repeated and useless instructions related to it:

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    n = len(array)
    while n:
        for i in range(n - 1):
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
        n -= 1
    return array

def main():
   array = [1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 6]
   array = bubble_sort(array)
   print(array)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Now it works. But your `while` loop could just be a `for` loop: `for n in range(len(array), 0, -1)`.